# prevent callback from running until animation ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function with a callback that will execute at the end.
Basically I'm adding a css class to a div that will animate it, and want to remove that div when the animation terminates. This is how I'm doing it :

```
this.animate = function(cssClass, callback) {
        $(div).addClass(cssClass);
            callback();

    }
```

And when calling this function :

```
this.animate('animated', function () {
     $(div).remove();
}
```

However, I noticed that the div got removed before the animation fires.

EDIT : here is the css class :

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeOutUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadeOutUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeOutUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
}

.animated.fadeOutUp {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
    -o-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
    animation-name: fadeOutUp;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.25s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.25s;
    -o-animation-duration: 0.25s;
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
}
```

EDIT : (solution)
I solved this problem using the `one()` method as follows :

```
 $(div).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',   
    function(e) {

    // code to execute after animation ends

    $(this).remove();
    });
```

Hope it can help others facing the same problem.

Comment: What kind of animation are you using? Transition? Css animation?

Comment: @abdelk but what kind of animation? Could you post relevant CSS code applied to animated class?

Comment: 1. quick and dirty method: setTimeout; 2. listen to `animationend` event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/animationend

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use a jQuery animation function, which has a `complete` event callback you can hook up when the animation completes. Pass a set of CSS rules over your animation function.

```
this.animate = function(cssRules, callback) {
  $(div).animate(cssRules, 1000, "linear", function() {
    console.log('animation completed');
    callback(); //executes your callback here
  });
}
```

`cssRules` are the rules defined in your argument `cssClass`; it would look like:

```
{ 
  height: 200,
  width: 400,
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

Start with something easy; change only one css rule e.g. `font-size` or `height`. There may have a way to animate on the basis of a css class, Google it, you never know.

See the documentation at the very end of the page (about the complete callback): http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Hope this helps,

R.

Comment: I'm going to check that, I guess it's cleaner.